# Error parsing JSON (MismatchedInputException)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm having problems parsing JSON, this is the error:

```
out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<packagename....>` out of START_OBJECT token
```

And I know why it is happening I just don't know how to fix it. This JSON works:

```
{
    "status_code": "SUCCESS",
    "time": {
        "date": "Mar 23, 2021 1:14:39 AM"
    },
    "info": [
        {
            "person": "2.2",
            "role": "TEACHER"
        },
        {
            "person": "2.3",
            "role": "TEACHER"
        }
    ]
}
```

This one does not:

```
{
    "status_code": "SUCCESS",
    "time": {
        "date": "Mar 23, 2021 3:49:27 AM"
    },
    "info": {
        "id": "1",
        "person": [
            {
                "identifier": "John",
                "role": "TEACHER"
            },
            {
                "identifier": "Homer",
                "role": "TEACHER"
            },
            {
                "identifier": "Michael",
                "role": "TEACHER"
            },
            {
                "identifier": "Sarah",
                "role": "TEACHER"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be the `{` character in front of the `info` field because with `[` works. So this is the method I'm using to parse the JSON:

```
public Mono<PersonResponse> searchById(String id) {
        return webClient.get().uri(id).retrieve().bodyToMono(PersonResponse.class);
}
```

Also tried:

```
public Mono<PersonResponse[]> searchById(String id) {
            return webClient.get().uri(id).retrieve().bodyToMono(PersonResponse[].class);
}
```

Error right on line: 1, column: 1. Any suggestions of how to implement the method?

EDIT: Added classes.

PersonResponse:

```
public class PersonResponse implements Serializable{
        
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7506229887182440471L;
        
    public String status_code;
    public Timestamp time;  
    public List<PersonDetails> info;

    public PersonResponse() {}

    ...getters / setters / toSting
```

PersonDetails:

public class PersonDetails implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1294417456651475410L;

private int id;
private List<Person> person;

public PersonDetails(int version) {
    super();
    this.version = version;
}

...getters / setters / toSting
```

Person

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3290753964441709903L;
    
    private String identifier;
    private String role;
    
    public Person(String identifier, String role) {
        super();
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.role = role;
    }

    ...getters / setters / toSting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the JSON necessarily, it's that the JSON structure doesn't match your `PersonResponse` class. There's an info variable in PersonResponse that requires an array of what I assume to be persons, in the second example you're trying to push an object in there, which you can't. You have to either change your JSON, which you don't seem to want in this case, or the class you're trying to parse it to.

You need to restructure the info variable in `PersonResponse` to match the object you're trying to parse to it.

Comment: Going to edit the post with the classes, but I don't think that is the problem, because I do have an ArrayList of Persons and the object for the ID in the info.

Comment: @user If you have a list, how do you expect a JSON object to map/deserialize to it?

Comment: @DFSFOT You were right, I changed the structure of Info variable and it worked, thanks for your time.